# Recursion in Go for coding question: Product Sum

Tags: go, recursion

I've been practicing coding interview questions with this current example of Product Sum with Go. Basically, you need to take a nested array and return it's product sum.

Example: [1,3,[2,[5],-3],7] = 1 + 3 + 2*(2-3) + 3*(5) + 7 = 24

Which should also be equal to: 1 + 3 + 2*(2) + 2*(-3) + 3*5 + 7 = 24

However, when I try implementing this in code I can only get the first example.

```
func ProductSum(array []interface{}) int {
    sum := productSum(array, 1)
    fmt.Println(sum)
    return sum
}

func productSum(array SpecialArray, multiplier int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, el := range array {
        if cast, ok := el.(SpecialArray); ok {
            sum += productSum(cast, multiplier+1)
        } else if cast, ok := el.(int); ok {
            sum += cast
        }
    }
    return sum * multiplier
}
```

If I change `sum += cast` to `sum += cast * multiplier`, and change `return sum * multiplier` to `return sum` - then the function doesn't work as expected. I've tried working through the recursive stack on this but am still confused.

Comment: What is the input to the ProductSum function? Show how it is declared

Comment: Unfortunately this is through a coding interview site and I don't have access to the input or how the function is called. :/

Comment: You have a `SpecialArray` type. If the input array has `[]interface{}` elements in it, the type assertion will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code the "array notation" should be transformed to following equation:

`[1,3,[2,[5],-3],7] = 1*(1 + 3 + 2*(2 + 3 * (5) - 3) + 7) = 1 + 3 + 2*(2 - 3 + 15) + 7 = 11 + 14 * 2 = 39`

or

`[1,3,[2,[5],-3],7] = 1*(1 + 3 + 2*(2 + 3 * (5) - 3) + 7) = 1 + 3 + 2*(-1) + 6 * 5 + 7 = 11 - 2 + 30 = 39`

In your interpretation each level of nesting increases the multiplier by one.

Could you paste the exact content of this exercise?

Edit:

To get 24 in result your code should look like this:

```
func ProductSum(array []interface{}) int {
    sum := productSum(array, 1)
    fmt.Println(sum)
    return sum
}

func productSum(array []interface{}, multiplier int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, el := range array {
        if cast, ok := el.([]interface{}); ok {
            sum += productSum(cast, multiplier+1)
        } else if cast, ok := el.(int); ok {
            // Multiplier is applied only to integers in current slice.
            sum += multiplier * cast
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

The sum of an array is always multiplied by the its level of nesting.

Comment: As commented previously I actually don't have anymore content than this as it's through a coding interview site. However funny enough I think I have a hunch from the way you formatted the expanded arrays. It seems the recursion stack forces you to save the multiplier for the end, because you may get invalid results to immediately apply the multiplier if you aren't done moving down the recursion stack and getting everything that's within the current subarrays. Does that make sense or am I guessing wrong? haha

Comment: I've added working example which returns 24 input provided in the question. And you could solve this problem using recursion thanks to the fact that `x*(y+z) = x*y + x * z`.